# Jquery: How to call a function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a check box called, On click of that check box I am calling a function below.

```
 $('#checkbox-id').on('click', function(){
    alert("clicked");
 }).each(function(){this.checked = ace.settings.is('main-container', 'fixed')})
```

Same method I want to call from different function. First I need to check weather checkbox is checked or not after that I need to call function once checkbox is check for this I am using this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if(document.getElementById('checkbox-id').checked){
       $('#checkbox-id').click() // getting called but also unchecking checkbox it should not uncheck
   }
});
```

This is working but it also unchecking checkbox which I don't want.

So How can I call that function without unchecking checkbox.

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sohampshetty/dL3cj1sL/3/) to reproduce.

Comment: This should work, `$('#checkbox-id').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#ace-settings-add-container').click();
    }
});`

Comment: please see question I have edited.

Comment: Using `change` event listener on select or radio button is always a better practice

Comment: click event is for button element.

Comment: can you provide a  fiddle ?

Comment: @Pekka it already written I cant change

Comment: @JSantosh check jsfiddle

Comment: @SohamShetty, which version of JS are you using . i need this to determine whether the click is done by user or JS.

Comment: @JSantosh click will be done by user. in my function I want to call first function that's why I am writing this code " $('#checkbox-id').click() "

Comment: @SohamShetty i forgot to say it is checkbox click. whether checkbox click is done by user or by JS when button clicked

Comment: @JSantosh uncheck is done by JS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91712/discussion-between-j-santosh-and-soham-shetty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only **workaround** not proper solution

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   if(document.getElementById('checkbox-id').checked) {
        $('#checkbox-id').click() // getting called but also unchecking checkbox should not uncheck
        $('#checkbox-id').prop('checked', true);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check If Check Box Is Checked Like :

```
$(document.body).on('change', '#chkID', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            // CHECK BOX IS CHECKED
        }
        else {
            // CHECK BOX IS NOT CHECKED
        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8osfwfLf/)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring your function instead of using an anonymous function:

```
function handle_click() {
    alert("clicked");
}

$('#checkbox-id').on('click', handle_click);

$(document).ready(function(){
   if(document.getElementById('checkbox-id').checked){
       handle_click();
   }
});
```

Comment: already written by PL I just want to call that function from my function

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Did you see I called `handle_click` twice?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this ,this will fire the alert once the checkbox become checked

```
 $('#checkbox-id').on('click', function () {
                    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
                        alert("clicked");
                    }               
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `trigger()` instead:

```
$('#checkbox-id').trigger('click');
```